# Resolve Fixnum error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, fixnum

I have a parameter (params[:authorization]) that comes from the URL, as you can see:

```
authorization_selected = params[:authorization]
new_parcel = params[:new_parcel].to_i

puts authorization_selected.class (in the console show type String)
puts new_parcel.class (in the console show type Fixnum)
```

In my controller, have:

```
@portability = Portability.new
@portability.employee_id = authorization_selected.employee_id
```

However this returns an error:

```
undefined method `employee_id' for 3:Fixnum
```

I need that both was integer. How do it?

Comment: Your code sample and error message do not match. authorization is a String but the error message says it is a Fixnum.

Comment: Please post the full code, not a sample of it.  What you have put should give a different error because `authorization_selected` is a string. not a fixnum according to your first section of code.  Do you mean to do `@portability.employee_id = new_parcel`?

Comment: no, @ portabilitity.employee_id = @authorization.employee_id  (but don't work). And new_parcel is a value enter by input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the `employee_id` method on `authorization_selected`which is a String and does not provide this method.
Obviously this does not work. You probably want to do

```
@portability = Portability.new
@portability.employee_id = authorization_selected
```

assuming that `params[:employee]` contains the `employee_id` and `Portability` is an ActiveModel or an ActiveRecord.

Perhaps you can change your form that the value can be assigned through the initializer?

Comment: Mind to change copy-pasted `= authorization_selected` to [likely] correctly mentioned `= params[:employee]`? :)

Comment: Why negative me? I lost more than six points because this : (

Comment: authorization belongs to employee, portability belongs to authorization and employee

Comment: People are going to downvote you if you post questions that are not well formed. This question of yours is not well formed. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask (Or the Portuguese version, if you prefer: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).